# Magento 2 how to get product multi select attribute?

Tags: magento2, product, multiselect-attribute

How I can get the value of multi select attribute. 
I tried with below code but all return null

```
$pro->getCustomAttribute('offer')
$pro->getAttributes('offer');
$pro->getAttributeText('offer')
```

Comment: where you want to fetch ?

Comment: @SaurabhRanjan on list.phtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$pro->getAttributeText(‘offer’)
```

is the correct method to call. However, you need to make sure that the attribute is joined to your collection.

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect(‘offer’)
```